# How to add two links on the same line in PHP or CSS

Tags: html, css

Actually, I had created a separate file for my footer links and it is called footer.php and I had assigned some links to their respective variables. And then I used the include() feature and added that file in my main .php file. The code is given below.

```
Code for footer.php

<?php
$about_us = "<div class="about-link"><a href="domain/about_us.php">About Us</a></div>"
$follow_me = "<div class="follow-me"><a href="domain/follow_me.php">Follow Me</a></div>"
?>
```

And here is the code for main file.

```
Code for main.php

<?php
include 'domain/footer.php'

echo "$about_us and $follow_me"
?>
```

And this code shows me the links in an separate line like the example given below.

About Us

and

Follow Me

I had not placed any ***br*** code. So, I am thinking how it is occurring as I did all the things correctly (I think so). Waiting for you expert advice.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP and is the default behaviour of `div` tags, displayed as blocks. I would advise to learn some more HTML before trying to do PHP, else you will have a really hard time troubleshooting your future errors, and from where I see it there will be many of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the behavior of `div` tag. A `div` is a *block*, and as such will appear like having a line break. Instead, you may want to use a `span` tag, which is *inline*, or don't close your `div` between your links.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is what is causing the extra lines. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.about-link, .follow-me { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, what about the 'and' in the echo part?

Comment: The "and" is just plain text not wrapped in a div. It should not be displayed as a block.

Answer (score 0):

The div element is a block element, not an inline element, thats why both of the links in a new line. Simply remove the divs around the links or add the following CSS:

```
.about-link, .follow-me {float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the two links are enclosed in div tags. This will automatically start them on new lines.

Enclose them in spans or use float:left to put them beside each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any other tags which work like _italic_ `div`tag

Comment: @user3507192, These tags are called `inline elements`. Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements

Answer (score 0):

because you have placing the hyperlink tag **anchor tag** inside the div thats why u r getting link in two different lines.. /

if u want to get both link in same link then you have to set the css for these div

```
.about-link, .follow-me {
 display: inline-block !important; 
}
```

**!important** just to prevent the case if these class already have display property so this !important will overwrite and will tell the browser to render this one only not the prev. defined one ..

Answer (score 0):

in your css you can add `float:left;` to .about-link and .follow-me - I would also consider adding a margin-right to put some spacing between the two.

Ideally, you would add a footer class so you don't have to define float for every link.

```
<div class="about-link ftr"><a href="domain/about_us.php">About Us</a></div>
<div class="follow-me ftr"><a href="domain/follow_me.php">Follow Me</a></div>
```

define a new class in your css `.ftr` with float:left and desired margin/spacing

The "and" is in your PHP, this line:

```
echo "$about_us and $follow_me"
```

should be:

```
echo "$about_us $follow_me"
```

Comment: But I want to use the 'and' in the echo itself. Isn't any way to solve out that problem.

Comment: if you want "and" to show up between the two links then wrap that in a div as well.. echo "$about_us <div class=\"ftr\">and</div> $follow_me"

Answer (score 0):

you have used div in the variable `$about_us` and `$follow_me`. Div is block html element.   for this reason you have got new line.
You need css for displaying block divs into inline.

try like this:

```
about-link, .follow-me {
  display: inline-block;
}
```